# The relation between the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem and construction of reals

Tags: logic, model-theory

The Löwenheim–Skolem theorem directly implies that if a countable first-order theory has an infinite model then it has a countable model. That leads to peculiar things like the so-called Skolem’s “paradox”, which can be recast as saying that ZFC has a countable model.

I wonder if we can turn that paradox on its head, so to say. If we start with natural numbers, we can construct integers, rationals and, finally, by eg Dedekind cuts, reals. And the final step is not like the others, because we suddenly jump from countable infinity to uncountable infinity. And those real numbers are not really numbers in the conventional sense of atomic objects but rather a model of them that behaves just like reals given an appropriate interpretation.

What I am getting at, to put in a succinct but sloppy phrase, we only need to believe in natural numbers to be able to reason about real numbers.

And I can’t help but to see a connection between an ability to move through cardinalities implied by the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem and the ability to construct reals out of natural numbers. Is there a conceptual connection between those two phenomena or am I overthinking it?

Comment: There is a sort of connection. The real numbers are uncountable, yet they are constructed from the natural numbers. This implies that there cannot be a first-order characterisation of the reals using a countable language. We need to move beyond first-order logic into the realm of second-order logic, which we can do by describing the reals in terms of sets of rational numbers or by using second-order axioms like Dedekind or Cauchy completeness.

Answer (score 1):

> And I can’t help but to see a connection between an ability to move through cardinalities implied by the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem and the ability to construct reals out of natural numbers. Is there a conceptual connection between those two phenomena or am I overthinking it?

I don't quite understand what you have in mind but two comments.

1. We always do mathematics in a language with a finite alphabet, e.g. English or the language of mathematics or first-order logic or what have you. That means we only ever have the ability to talk directly about countably many things in mathematics. In that sense no matter how complicated the objects we define are we only ever *talk about them* using a countable set of utterances. This could be considered part of the conceptual point of Lowenheim-Skolem, although this general observation applies even to second-order logic while Lowenheim-Skolem doesn't.
2. The Lowenheim-Skolem paradox applies to the first-order theory of the real numbers as well, and implies that it has a countable model. This theory is the theory of [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field), and an explicit example of a countable model of it is the field $\mathbb{R}_{alg}$ of real algebraic numbers. This means that first-order logic is not capable of expressing completeness; to do that we need second-order logic.